# what should i do if android phone becomes low on storage and i cant insert anymore data into Sqlite

Tags: android, android-sqlite, local-storage

I have 2 databases an Sqlite database that is the local storage on the android device and Mysql database which is the online database,the user inserts data into the Sqlite database which then sends it to the Mysql database via sync process,my problem here is , what if the Sqlite database becomes very full i mean if the phone becomes very low on storage the user will not be capable of inserting data into the Sqlite,Mysql database has infinite storage(big storage).

Comment: The device will have other issues than just not being able to insert data for your app. You probably shouldn't be storing GB worth of data anyway

Comment: As @cricket_007 pointed out, you don't probably need 'gigs' worth of data immediately available to your app. Try to keep the most frequently used/most important chunks in your SQLite db and let the server deal the rest. If you ever need that other data, make a request to the server and download it in parts as you need them.

Comment: Start deleting old data from your own DB that the user is less interested in seeing if you hit a certain max of storage space

Comment: when the user first downloads the app the database will be empty and then the user starts inserting data like small amounts of data,they will not be that big its just a calendar where people can insert coming events/date/time.

Comment: I think you're over estimating how large your dataset is. If it's just calendar data, you can use Google Calendar provider, not a Mysql database.  Think about busy people with multiple meetings a day, for months or years at a time. They aren't getting full devices

Answer (score 0):

Notify the User about that and point to the fact that storage have to be cleared.